# Cross-domain workaround to load an external page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the jQuery documentation:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

As mentioned there as an additional note:

> Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject
>   to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve
>   data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol.

Is there any way to bypass this limitation?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create a proxy page that requests the external page on the server. The implementation is dependent on the technology being used, but the idea is that you can then make an ajax call to your proxy page instead which will be on the same domain as the calling page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! "_One way is to create a proxy page that requests the external page on the server._" How can I do it using `PHP`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several ways to get around this. But I would strongly suggest [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) (Cross-Domain Resource Sharing). CORS is the emerging standard for addressing cross-domain Ajax. This is replacing approaches such as JSONP (which has known security issues).

Unfortunately, CORS is not supported by older IE versions (6-9), but there are established polyfills for browsers which do not natively implement CORS. [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) is one such polyfill.

At a basic level, below is a sample request (from the MDN link above), where the browser generates a request with the **Origin** header, indicating the domain of the request, which is validated by the endpoint:

```
GET /resources/access-control-with-credentials/ HTTP/1.1
Host: bar.other
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.5; en-US; rv:1.9.1b3pre) Gecko/20081130 Minefield/3.1b3pre
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://foo.example/examples/credential.html
Origin: http://foo.example
Cookie: pageAccess=2
```

An Ajax endpoint supporting CORS may respond with the appropriate headers, which the browser validates. See Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials in this example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 Dec 2008 01:34:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.0.61 (Unix) PHP/4.4.7 mod_ssl/2.0.61 OpenSSL/0.9.7e mod_fastcgi/2.4.2 DAV/2 SVN/1.4.2
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://foo.example
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: pageAccess=3; expires=Wed, 31-Dec-2008 01:34:53 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 106
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/plain
```

The browser may also send a pre-flight (using the **OPTIONS** verb) which can indicate to the server what headers or verbs the Ajax call will use. The pre-flight is actually a separate call from the primary Ajax call, but is only invoked under certain conditions.

Many web servers (IIS, Apache) support CORS through modules. The servers will require configuration to white-list origins, allowed verbs, headers, etc. Wildcarding can also be used but is not recommended.

Comment: CORS seems promising, but I'd really appreciate it if you provided a Fiddle so I know how to use it in action. Thanks!

Comment: For browsers which support CORS, the client (browser) will send a pre-flight request, which is a sort of handshake before the primary request, or the actually request immediately depending on HTTP verb, whether custom request headers are involved, etc. The server serving the Ajax response will also need to support CORS, responding with the appropriate headers and actual response data.